# Why is Spring boot application has a default mapper

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a simple spring boot app and every time, DispatcherServlet processes something which I dont know where it comes from. When I call any REST API, this is being called before the actual one.

This is the message in the debug. Can anyone guide me if I am missing the basics.

```
DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing POST request for [/login]
```

Actually I have a mapped API with this name, so not sure how this is being set

Here is my controller, the moment I call /getUserInfo along with that, /login is also called. My whole controller is annotated with @RestController.

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public List<User> login(@RequestParam(value = "userID") String userID,@RequestParam(value = "userPassword" ) String userPassword) {
    return service.checkUser(userEmail, userPassword, repository);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/getUserInfo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public User getUserInfo(@RequestParam("userID") String userID, User user) {
    return service.getuserDetail(userID, user, repository);
}
```

Also the order is random based on the trigger. here is the complete stack trace

```
2016-11-12 09:16:48.963 DEBUG 9848 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/getUserInfo]
2016-11-12 09:16:48.963 DEBUG 9848 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /getUserInfo
2016-11-12 09:16:48.965 DEBUG 9848 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Returning handler method [public com.boot.model.User com.boot.controller.ConsumerController.getUserInfo(java.lang.String,com.boot.model.User)]
2016-11-12 09:16:48.966 DEBUG 9848 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/getUserInfo] is: -1
2016-11-12 09:16:48.968 DEBUG 9848 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing POST request for [/login]
2016-11-12 09:16:48.971 DEBUG 9848 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /login
2016-11-12 09:16:48.973 DEBUG 9848 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Returning handler method [public java.util.ArrayList<com.boot.model.User> com.boot.controller.ConsumerController.login(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)]
2016-11-12 09:16:49.074 DEBUG 9848 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.cors.DefaultCorsProcessor        : Skip CORS processing: request is from same origin
```

Here is my pom.xml

```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!--<dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>angularjs</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.9</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

     <dependency> <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId> <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId> 
        <version>2.11.0</version> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId> 
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId> <version>2.11.0</version> </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20160810</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.websocket-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: Can you show your Controller code? Do you have Spring Security on the classpath?

Comment: @BrianClozel I have added the controller code to my initial post

Comment: where is your /getUserInfo method... you posted login method 2 times

Comment: Can you paste the complete line of log statements `processing GET request for [/getUserInfo]` and `processing POST request for [/login]` .. I would like to see which component is actually logging that

Comment: Do you have CORS related configuration? Post your application.properties or any other configuration file you are using.

Comment: @Lucky No I dont have CORS related config. I have application.properties which has only the datasource, debug  and hibernate information

Comment: Then I suggest you look into pom.xml for any unwanted dependencies and remove it. Maybe that's causing problem. Post your pom file.

Comment: @Lucky I checked my pom.xml. I dont see any unwanted dependencies.. I will attach it to my initial post

Comment: Finally it was something to do with my form in html which had an action to login.. I know this is a very basic one but I missed to look here and looking at bigger picture

Answer (score 0):

There was no issue with the Spring mapper. It was something to do with my HTML where these buttons were wrapped in a form tag and which had an login action. I missed this somehow and was looking at the bigger picture.. Thanks for all your inputs